# Facebook Marketing API / Insights data

Tags: facebook, api, ads

I'm trying to get insights data for every single campaign / ad we have on facebook by using Facebook Marketing API with following call on the **Facebook Graph Explorer**:

```
act_<my_ID>/campaigns?fields=insights{reach,spend}
```

Result: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME25B.png)

I only get insights data for the 3 recent campaigns. I've tried to add time_range and date_preset yet I still can't get no insights data from the other campaigns / ads.

I'm able to see the spend and reach on Facebook Business manager itself, so I know the numbers exists.

Anyone know a solution to this? Or why this is happening.

Thank you very much!

Regards,

Y

Answer (score 1):

```
act_<my_ID>?fields=campaigns{insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}){reach,spend},ads{insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}){reach,spend}}}
```

try this o